# Input для времени в формате 00:00:00

Tags: html, input, datetime, время

Искал в интернете поле для времени. Нашел [несколько ссылок](https://www.google.ru/search?q=html%20input%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8&newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=GkhhYcOMDo31qwH877jIAQ&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYWFWKv27Btyb6sY64pp2IsCGSyfiyaBG&oq=html%20input%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBEKMCOgUIABCABDoICAAQsQMQgwE6CAguEIAEELEDOgsILhCABBDHARCvAToNCAAQgAQQsQMQRhD_AVDHB1ipQWDae2gBcAB4AIABdIgBoQmSAQQxMS4ymAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz), но там везде `input` для времени в формате `00:00` ([пример](http://programmerbook.ru/html/input/type/time/)). Как сделать в формате 00:00:00 (то есть с секундами)?

Comment: [а вот так](https://www.google.ru/search?q=html+input+для+времени+секунды&newwindow=1&sxsrf=AOaemvKK3eNNug_9N3OU7BBouwutbahJzQ%3A1633767416228&ei=-E9hYZqzDY7urgSp54zQBw&ved=0ahUKEwiaj_Xz8bzzAhUOt4sKHakzA3oQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=html+input+для+времени+секунды&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEBYQHjoICCEQFhAdEB46BQghEKABOgkIIRAKEKABECpKBAhBGABQ9esDWJuSBGCnlwRoAXACeACAAYIBiAHbBZIBAzcuMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

Comment: @ArchDemon по той ссылке, которую вы дали показывается как добавить секунды к элементу datetime, а не time.

Comment: @0xdb а вы не знаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дабы показать что вы нагло врёте что по моей ссылке нет решения, то вот вам рабочий пример.

```html
<input type="time" step=1>
```

Comment: извините, я просмотрел.